# What is the difference between $lt and $not $gt in MongoDB?

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql

`db.restaurants.find( { "grades.score": { $not: { $gt: 10 }}}, { "grades.score": 1})`

and

`db.restaurants.find( { "grades.score": { $lt: 10 }}, { "grades.score": 1})`

What would be the difference between these two queries? (i.e. less than 10, and not greater than 10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query operators in MongoDB are type sensitive.  If the value in the document is a different type than the argument in the query, it will not match.

This can be leveraged using the `$not` operator to query specific types

Such as:
`{$gte: ""}` will match all string values, but not other types
`{$not: {$gte: ""}` will match all non-string values

For example, if you had these documents in the collection:

```
{value: 10},
{value: 5},
{value: 'A'},
{value: 'B'},
{value: null},
{}, //value is missing
```

```
A query for            Would match

{value: {$gt:7}}       {value: 10}


{value: {$lt:7}}       {value: 5}


{value: {$not:{$gt:7}} {value: 5},
                       {value: 'A'},
                       {value: 'B'},
                       {value: null},
                       {}
```

Whether this is useful depends very much on how the data is structured and inserted.

Answer (score 1):

Just a wild guess - Not Greater than is the same as Less than or equal to... not Less than. Mathematics is only my minor, but I'm pretty sure!